For pipeline notifications under project settings in Azure DevOps, Can I create a new subscription for when a build fails for a specific pipeline
I have my pipeline running in the ADO, I want to setup notification when my pipeline fails on a scheduled run, currently I have set up a new subscription for when the build fails. This works, only problem is that there are multiple pipelines under my project (Subscriber).
What I want to do is setup notification for when one specific pipeline fails on schedule. Is there any solution for this?

You can use filter Definition name = YourPipelineName when creating a new subscription. Select your pipeline from the drop-down bar.

At the same time, you need to turn off the default Build completes notification from user-level Notifications. Otherwise, you will receive notifications when other pipelines complete.
Go to User settings -> Notifications -> Turn off default Build completes.

